# Touch pad does not want to reenable in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad, xinput

I’ve been having issues with this yesterday. I cannot do ANYTHING with my touch pad on Linux Mint specifically, I accidentally disabled it and now it does not re-enable using fn+f9. This issue does not happen in Ubuntu. It disables and reenables. I tried using xinput and it shows up as ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad. Someone please help!

Comment: When booting Linux Mint, is the touchpad enabled in the BIOS/UEFI firmware? If so, it's likely a driver issue, where Ubuntu includes the driver by default and Linux Mint does not - laptop manufacturers don't usually offer non-Windows drivers, so you'll likely have to manually search for it by the manufacturer of the touchpad itself _(e.g. Synaptics, etc.)_

Comment: @JW0914 The weird thing is that it was working until yesterday - where i mispressed a certain combination of keys and it turned it off - I don't think it's a driver issue